# How is Shooting Star treated when a stock is in uptrend

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, futures, technical-analysis

So I've started learning Candlesticks and I stumbled on Inverted Hammer i.e. shooting star. I was wondering what would I do with it when it appears in a uptrend stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shooting Star is easily identified by the presence of a small body with an upper shadow at least two times greater than the body found at the top of an uptrend, and sends a warning that the top may be near.

After a strong up-trend has been in effect, the atmosphere is bullish. The price opens and trades higher. The bulls are in control. But before the end of the day, the bears step in and take the price back down to the lower end of the trading range, creating a small body for the day. The long upper shadow indicates that sellers had started stepping in at these levels. The longer the shadow the stronger the indication that the bears have taken control and the trend may be near a reversal.

An Inverted Hammer, a similar looking candle to the shooting start, on the other hand, is found at the bottom of a down-trend and may be an indication of a bullish reversal of the down-trend.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote for a correct definition of the pattern in question and what actually happens in the market to give the candle it's shape from someone who has no understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. p.s. I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: Well I upvoted your question.

Comment: ...And finally cosmic balance was brought to the universe, with my humble upvote to your answer... actually very informative and useful, IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

Ideally, you'd want to trade in known areas - that is, areas of value where behavior is relatively well-known and predictable. This provides you with a clear picture of where you should set your profit targets (based on levels of support) and stop-losses (based on levels of resistance). Both your profit target and stop-loss are obviously being set slightly above these levels, as you want to take profits before hitting support, and only stop your loss if the level of resistance has been breached.

Secondly, you must account for additional context by looking at various time frames such as the strength of your levels of support and resistance as well as the general trends of the stock. If the stock appears overextended and overbought on the longer time frames, this obviously disfavors taking long trades when the shorter-term market direction is bearish. Similarly, that "support" you identified is obviously less significant if it has only been tested on the shorter time frames and has no significance on the longer ones.

Also, consider the timing based on daily volatility. Has this stock just run out of steam or has yet to get going today? Especially if you are a shorter-term trader, it's important to be aware of factors such as the daily opening hours and the approach of the weekend.

Overall, a shooting star is only really significant if all these other factors play into it. It's just a price action-based pattern that signifies potential reversal during a bullish run. Emphasis on "potential" - the rest is up to the understanding of the trader of concepts such as VWAP, MACD, RSI, general trend direction, levels of support and resistance and their relative strength, volatility, daily volatility, and probably much more that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the OP's question. A shooting star does not signify potential strength, it actually signifies the potential end to an uptrend. Candlestick charting can be viewed in combination with other western technical analysis indicators or they can be used primarily by themselves. The main purpose and use of candlestick charting is to gauge the psychology of the market.

Comment: Whoops, I messed up the terminology of the shooting star and the hammer. I will adjust my answer accordingly. Although, I would like to add, adjusting for that, the answer is pretty clear. It can and must be viewed in conjunction with additional analysis or else you're hammering (pun intended) your win rate unnecessarily.

Comment: That is also incorrect, the Japanese have been using candlestick charting for hundreds of years with no help from western technical indicators. You should really do more research on the matter before you splurt out your beliefs and try to pass them off as facts!

Comment: It takes about five minutes to code up a script that uses the shooting star pattern to execute long and short positions for you. If you could find a trading strategy that outperforms any trivial kind such as buying and holding reliable stocks or index ETFs, then everyone would do it to start their own fund. Especially since you could find practically an infinite amount of them, so scaling is not a problem.

I have backtested many dozens of popular trading strategies and patterns; they all fail. If you can come up with it, someone else can too. If you can prove me wrong, please post results..

Comment: Also, "an <insert race> has been doing it for a long time" is obviously a fallacy; people have been subjected to confirmation bias since the start of the human race. Folk medicine with no basis in science whatsoever is quite often as old as the plague it feigns to cure. I would much rather see results than to argue about plain fallacies in circles.

Comment: What is "an <insert race> has been doing it for a long time" even supposed to mean? Obviously you know practically nothing about candlestick charting, you don't even know when a shooting star should be used. For your information, the Japanese invented candlestick charting almost 300 years ago, the west has been using them for less than 30 years. And if you did even a little bit of research on them you would know that the main purpose and use of candlestick charting are to gauge the psychology of the market.

Comment: The first part seems trivial to me. What it means is that it's a fallacy; "The Japanese have been using it for hundreds of years" is not an argument to any claim that it works under any conditions. Whether it does or doesn't, a bunch of people using it for a long time means nothing in terms of performance.

And I agree with what it indicates, which is why you need additional indicators for a buy set-up. And again, if you disagree, post results! I would love to see them, unironically.

Comment: OMG - you are stupid! By the way, your answer is still wrong!

Comment: When words fail, results prevail. I would love for you to demonstrate, either through an Excel file, videos, or any other form that is convenient, what kind of results you are able to get by simply trading shooting star patterns without any additional constraints. I will very much appreciate it and we may both learn from the exchange!

Comment: Unlike you, I am a busy person and don't have to jump to prove anything for you, especially when you can't even answer the OP's question and still think that the shooting star is a sign of potential strength! You are just an example of lazy research!

Comment: If you were never willing to prove your point, then I must respectfully tell you that I sincerely do not appreciate you wasting my damn time with nonsensical argumentation. I have tried to backtest dozens and dozens of strategies algorithmically and so far next to none of them work. But since proving a falsehood is a lot harder than posting good results, I ask of you the very simple and straightforward feat of posting your results with what you propose is such a good indicator that it requires no further analysis. If you weren't willing to do that, engaging in a discussion was futile to boot.

Comment: Again, all this backtesting of dozens of strategies algorithmically does not mean anything if you still think a shooting start is a sign of potential strength - if you plug in BS you get BS in return! As I said, you really need to get a better understanding of what candlestick charting is all about and stop being such a lazy researcher - you can start here: https://www.tradeciety.com/understand-candlesticks-patterns/

Comment: Ah, yes, I was talking about the inverted hammer all along, so I screwed up the directional aspect of my comment. Obviously, when I see it on a chart, I know what it is and why, regardless of the terminology. But in communication... Getting the wording right is rather crucial. However, this still is scarcely relevant as what matters to me is results. I will keep backtesting and tinkering away at my trading strategies while you are essentially taking a misunderstanding and turning it into a tug of war rather than showing results or evidence. The point about using proper analysis still stands..

Comment: I told you on 4 occasions that you had your answer wrong, and it took you this long to correct it - that is an indication that your backtesting is worthless, because as I have already said you are putting incorrect garbage in to get incorrect garbage out. By the way, your attempt at trying to make it seem like you were talking about the inverted hammer instead - well guess what you had that wrong as well, and you really haven't answered the OPs question! I wouldn't put real money on any of your trading, because it sounds like you have no idia of what you are doing!

Comment: You are confounding two things: Getting the naming wrong, and getting the analysis wrong. If I told you that a square was round, had no edges, and its surface area was pi times the square of its radius, would you have no clue about what I was referencing because I misnamed the concept? The collection of ideas that I put forth were coherent, clear, and correct, and you have done nothing to demonstrate otherwise - even though this takes fifteen minutes of coding on your part. I have tested the patterns, they don't work without additional analysis, case closed. Think I'm wrong? Show results.

Comment: You didn't just have the name wrong, you had the whole concept wrong. All you are trying to do now is cover your steps so you don't have to admit you were wrong. And that is you problem you might be able to code but if you don't know what you are coding about your result will be rubbish - admit you're wrong and please stop trading, you are just going to lose all your money!

Comment: You are still not providing the requested basic information to demonstrate that what you are saying has any validity. I have a few publicly available scripts, ideas and strategies available on https://www.tradingview.com/u/ralphschraven/ as well as dozens of scripts detailing a myriad of different hypothesized "profitable trading strategies". I have a YouTube channel on the topic. I didn't "get the concept wrong", because really, the answer is always "it depends on additional variables, just use the basic candle patterns in conjunction with your existing analysis". Don't believe me? Post proof

Comment: Hahaha, keep telling yourself that. By the way, you still haven't answered the OPs question. You keep ranting on about testing this and testing that. The OP just asked a simple question and you have just rambled on about everything but an answer to the original question! OMG, you have a hard head, no wonder you have trouble understanding simple concepts!

Comment: Please, do post proof, or stop arguing! Manual or algorithmic, I don't care. Post a screen shot, video, excel, anything other than garble that you come up with. If you make money by just dumping money into candlestick patterns with no further inquiry, you would make a lot of money selling courses or even selling your strategy to someone like me. All that's needed is some kind of proof.

I won't go into the same arguments that have passed the line of debate before; I've already addressed everything else you said.

Comment: Hahaha, yet you still have not answered the OPs questions. Just keep on ranting and rambling on!!!

Comment: My answer clearly reads that it signifies a potential reversal during a bullish run, which means it's a bearish signal and should be treated as a potential exit signal on a long position, or a potential entry for a short. Main emphasis being that additional analysis is required. Any reason you find this does not answer the OP's question or is not accurate which I hope could be evidenced by facts and figures rather than speculation and opinion?

Comment: Hahaha!!! Still going! How many attempts did it take you to get it right, was that 3 or 4? Yet you waffle on about everything but the shooting star for 3 long paragraphs before you even mention shooting start, and then you couldn't even get it right! The OP did not ask for a full-blown trading plan, the OP asked a simple question that you could not even get correct after 3 paragraphs of BS! Hahaha! What a joke!